# Quais os meios de replicações de tabelas entre servidores SQL?

Tags: sql-server, metodologia, replicação

Ao desenvolver um projeto, me deparei com a seguinte situação:

Temos um sistema, onde os usuários inserem informações no decorrer do processo produtivo, e no final é gerado um relatório.

Esses dados ficam salvos em um servidor SQL Server interno da empresa.
Preciso replicar os dados do relatório para um servidor que esta na nuvem (Azure).

Minha ideia:

> Quando for gerado o relatório na empresa, teria uma metodo (Async)
>   para tentar enviar o relatório para o servidor que esta na nuvem, caso
>   desse algo errado, entraria numa fila de espera, para ser enviado a
>   noite em um horário pre definido.

Mas, ao começar minha pesquisa, me deparei com algumas opções de replicação de dados entre servidores SQL, ja vi e trabalho com replicação entre servidores Hyper-V, mas pra SQL? nunca vi.

Tenho algumas duvidas ref. a essa replicação:

1. Caso um relatório seja editado na empresa, preciso que seja atualizado os dados na nuvem(azure).
2. Replicação esta disponível para qualquer versão do SQL Server? ou por exemplo, com versões express não é possível fazer replicação?
3. Os dados só serão manipulados na empresa, o servidor na nuvem é somente para visualização.

Comment: O snapshot server justamente para casos de relatórios e bancos somente de visualização. Tenta ver se mantendo as 2 conexões (Azure e Servidor) no Management Studio, é possível do Azure criar um snapshot do banco do outro servidor.

Comment: Pode tentar também criar um linked server entre os 2 serevidores (https://imasters.com.br/data/linked-server-pra-que-serve-e-quando-utilizar)